# Laravel 5 foreign key migration error

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, migration, laravel-5

i have an issue when i try to reset my migrations. I am using oracle sql so when the problem appeared the first think i've done i emptied the database now in my sqldeveloper i don't see the tables but if i run tinker every table is created. When i am trying to rollback my migrations i recieve an error referenced to the fact that i have foreign keys in some tables: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign key, but when i try to remove constraints artisan says that the table does not have this constraint.

Here are my migrations files:
categories table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('parent');
    });
    Schema::create('article_category', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('article_category');
    Schema::drop('categories');

}
```

articles table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->longText('title');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('excerpt',255);
        $table->longText('body');
        $table->integer('likes')->default(0);
        $table->longText('sourceName');
        $table->longText('linkURL');
        $table->integer('views')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    });


}



/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('articles');
}
```

my roles table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('role_user');
    Schema::drop('roles');
}
```

my tags table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('article_tag', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('article_tag');
    Schema::drop('tags');
}
```

So, basicaly my database is empty but i can't run anything. If i run php artisan migrate no tables are created, but if i run php artisan migrate:refresh/rollback/reset unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign key on dropping table articles. 
I've searched about this but i didn't find anything that suits my problem hope i'll find here the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `dropForeign` before you drop a table.

Example:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('article_tag', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('article_tag_article_id_foreign');
        $table->dropForeign('article_tag_tag_id_foreign');
    });
    Schema::drop('article_tag');
    Schema::drop('tags');
}
```

Comment: firstly i thought this is my problem because i didn't wrote correctly the dropforeign statement, but then i tried as you said and it gives me: cannot drop constraint - nonexistent constraint at the foreign key. i added this in my migration files:

Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('articles_user_id_foreign');
        });

Comment: Could this be a problem because i emptied my database?

Comment: I don't know, but to be sure you could remove your database and start with a fresh one.